# publish_post conflicts with save_post

Tags: posts, save-post, publish

my plugin has a save_post hook used to save the custom fields. now I add a publish_slider hook used to change a checkbox's status(`slider` is a custom post type). but it doesn't work properly.

the `save_post` hook is as below

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_post_func', 10, 1);
function save_post_func($post_id) {
  if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
    return;
  if ( isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'inline-save' )
    return;
  ...
  if(isset($_POST[$key])){
    update_post_meta($post_id,$key,$_POST[$key]);
  }
  else{
    if($field['type']=='checkbox'){
    update_post_meta($post_id,$key,0);
  }
}
```

this would set a default 0 to the checkbox when I save a new post and didn't set the checkbox, this is no problem.

and the `publish_slider` hook is as below

```
add_action('publish_slider', 'publish_slider_func', 10, 1);
function publish_slider_func($post_id) {
  ...
  update_post_meta($post_id, 'closeSlider', '1');
}
```

I hope when I publish the slider post, the `closeSlider` checkbox would be set to 1 automatically, but it wouldn't.

if I delete the `update_post_meta($post_id,$key,0);` in the first function, then the `publish` hook works

Comment: The `publish_posttype` action runs before the `save_post` action, so anything that happens in `save_post` will overwrite what you do in `publish_posttype`

Comment: @czerspalace thanks for your reply. so how about other `{status}_{post_type}` hooks? do they all run before `save_post`?

Comment: Yes, if you look here https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3618 `{new_status}_{post_type}` runs in `wp_transition_post_status` which runs before `save_post`